# How to Setup Wordpress with Amazon SES using Mail Queue Throttling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress, amazon-ses, subscribe2

I am trying to upgrade a Wordpress blog to use Amazon SES (Simple Email Service) with the Subscribe2 email notification plugin (see links below).  Currently I have the email working with the SES service, but I am running into rate limiting issues due to the fact that I have more than 1000+ subscribers.  I know that the SES service limits BCC emails to 50 recipients so in the Subscribe2 plugin I have truncated the BCC limit to 50 recipients per batch.  However since I am still at the initial sending limits I can only send 1 message (up to 50 recipients a piece) per second, and since the Subscribe2 plugin doesn't have any sort of throttling mechanism I'm looking for the paid Wordpress Mail Queue plugin to slowly send off the emails over a period of time, but I'm concerned that the SES plugin and the Mail Queue plugin will conflict each other because I believe they both override the same wp_mail() function (you can only override this once).  I may be mistaken, but does anyone have any insight into this?

Subscribe2 Plugin - http://subscribe2.wordpress.com/

Amazon SES Plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/amazon-ses-and-dkim-mailer/

Alternative SES Plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ses/

Wordpress Mail Queue Plugin - http://wpplugins.com/plugin/76/wordpress-mail-queue-wpmq/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I think I'm finally able to answer this question, so I'll just leave this here for others that might find it.  I took the plunge and bought the Mail Queue plugin and after playing around with it, I found that the Wordpress SES plugin amazon-ses-and-dkim-mailer doesn't actually hook into the wp_mail() function, it just redirects outgoing mail through the SES, but it seems to fail when the queue is actually processed.

The integration between subscribe2 and mail queue has been well tested by other blogs so that wasn't a problem.

The alternative plugin wp-ses is not compatible with the wordpress mail queue plugin because it does in fact also redefine the wp_mail() function, so that unfortunately is a no go.

The future road map on the wp-ses developer webpage states rate throttling as a future feature, so I think my best bet is to hold out for that plugin, unless someone knows of a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

Just published our mail queuing plug-in that will throttle. We've used it on a few sites.  It also handles multiple SMTP accounts, and non-delivery processing.  You can give it a try.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mail-queues/admin/